# ng show in ng repeat Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

I want hide ion-row if `value == null`
I use this code but it dose not work

```
<ion-row ng-show="item.Sex!= null">
                <ion-col col-6>
                    <h5 class="title">Porn Date</h5>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-2>
                    <h5 class="data">{{ item.Sex}}</h5>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
```

here the response list data

```
DayAfterPorn:null
Expected: null
Id:2
IsBuy:false
IsDead:false
IsDeleted: false
Num : 2
Sex: null## Heading ##
```

Why ng show dose not work even `value == null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use *ngif to hide the elment

Answer (score 2):

You should use like !item.Porn

```
<ion-row ng-show="!item.Porn">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `ng-show="item.Porn"` or `[hidden]="!item.Porn"`

I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> If you are using ionic 1+ version

```
<ion-row ng-show="item.Porn"> 
    <ion-col col-6> 
         <h5 class="title">Porn Date</h5> 
     </ion-col> 
    <ion-col col-2> 
        <h5 class="data">{{ item.Porn }}</h5> 
    </ion-col> 
</ion-row>
```

> If you are using ionic 3 version

```
<ion-row [hidden]="!item.Porn"> 
        <ion-col col-6> 
             <h5 class="title">Porn Date</h5> 
         </ion-col> 
        <ion-col col-2> 
            <h5 class="data">{{ item.Porn }}</h5> 
        </ion-col> 
    </ion-row>
```